# How to teach ethereum

Tags: contract-development

I want to hold small workshop or self learning course on how ethereum works how to create very basic contract (like named contract) and make it somehow visible to the participants what blocks are created how a transaction look like and so on.
question: what is the best / recommended way for this?

Comment: Welcome!  This is too broad, you could look at this StackExchange more, or resources like https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3vxvlx/starter_guide_almost_all_the_links_youll_need_to

Comment: I'm tempted to answer this question and I think it's not an _exact_ duplicate.

Comment: thanks @4chdn ... why not discuss about. much of the available simulators and test environments I tested are not really working (anymore). and as blockchain is a hard topic to grasp I think it is a very important topic to invest teaching the advantages and use cases.